How can I check If MobileAds.Initialize method called succesfully?
I'm making a mobile game with Unity. Game has Admob ads as banner and interstitial ad. At every x second, interstitial ad is appearing.
I want to set the player free. When the player enters the game, first menu opens. If internet is available he can click to the play button and play. So that he sees ads. So, when internet is not available he cannot play. But in the menu, if he opens the internet, he can play now. I wrote an algoritm. The banner ad is working as I wanted but not the interstitial ad. If I wanted to enable interstitial ad, I need to call initialize method. So, when the player opens the game with or without the internet, I need to know this method called succesfully or not called succesfully so that, I can call when the player opens the internet. Or is checking this impossible? In the opening, if I check is interstitial ad loaded succesfully then maybe I can understand the initialize method called but, what if the ad not opens because of another problem. So that, I called initialize method twice. I putted a bool to this method's inside but whether I turn on the internet or not, this bool returns true.
Initialize method:
    MobileAds.Initialize((InitializationStatus initStatus) =>
    {
        // This callback is called once the MobileAds SDK is initialized.
        LoadInterstitialAd();
    });
    


Look at the initialization status.

I had checked that. I rechecked now, there are 4 values. All of them are same even if internet is on or off.
Debug.Log(initStatus.getAdapterStatusMap());
Debug.Log(initStatus.ToString());
Debug.Log(initStatus.GetType());
Debug.Log(initStatus.GetHashCode());

Look at the adapter status for each adapter in the adapter status map.  The value is either READY or NOT_READY
